# PHP Unit testing - test sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, code-coverage, sqlsrv

I am trying to test a class which connects to the database via sqlsrv_connect (maybe mocking it) but I can't find the appropriate way to do it, I have researched a little bit but seems not to be able to find the correct tutorial. Every attempt fails with sqlsrv_connect not found.  Can anyone support?

```
    $this->conn = sqlsrv_connect($server_name, array("Database"=>$db_name));
```

Comment: Open up your command line and run `php -m | grep sql` do you have any sqlsrv entries in there? Is not you need to install sqlsrv

Comment: You need to install [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). `sqlsrv_connect()` is part of this driver.